# Using an alias to fill out data from one column for all rows

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I am currently trying to pull data from an off the shelf product relating to documents in a library.

We're needing to look at two specific fields to narrow down what we need so we've found the database they live in but the "field" sits in the same column as the rest of the fields - only differentiated with a prop_id.

What I'm looking to achieve is below - For every instance that the Site is "NULL" - how can I fill this with for example, Ace Technologies based on the matching tocid which relates to the document. For all instances of 994 tocid site should just be the same, with no NULLs.

[image]
The query to create the stored procedure is as below

```
SELECT        a.tocid,
              a.prop_id, 
              b.prop_name,
              a.str_val,
              CASE WHEN a.prop_id = '57' AND a.tocid = a.tocid 
                   THEN a.str_val 
              END as Site 
FROM            LaserRepository.dbo.toc AS d INNER JOIN
                         LaserRepository.dbo.propset AS c ON d.pset_id = c.pset_id INNER JOIN
                         LaserRepository.dbo.propval AS a INNER JOIN
                         LaserRepository.dbo.propdef AS b ON a.prop_id = b.prop_id ON d.tocid = a.tocid 
WHERE        (b.prop_id IN (59, 57, 127, 76, 86, 40, 686, 75, 637, 199, 85, 125, 128, 99, 675, 82, 688, 689)) 
AND (c.pset_id IN (4, 17, 24, 16, 7, 11)) 
AND c.pset_name = @template 
END
```

Comment: You need to adjust your case statement and include a subquery to fetch the Site value based on the tocid and prop_id

Comment: If there is only ever 1 instance of a null row per ```tocid``` then take a look into the LAG function. Something like this might do what you need ```SELECT LAG (Site) OVER (PARTITION BY tocid ORDER BY Site ) ...``` 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lag-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: So something like?  (SELECT str_val 
     FROM LaserRepository.dbo.propval 
     WHERE tocid = a.tocid) AS tocidtotal